# Unformated page

Tags: feature-request, bug

I'm not sure if this is intended, but a got following message on unformated white page:

*You have too many pending edits. Further edits cannot be submitted until prior edits have been approved.*

Just wanted to add some missing "version" tags to make it easier to filter questions.

Comment: More info on this feature: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not brwoser related. Steps to reproduce ...

- open X tabs, where you want to edit something
- make your edits ...

If your edit limit is reached and you hit (a not greyed out and clickable) "edit" link in another tab, you'll see that white page.

Answer (score 1):

The message is intended. But I think it should have appeared as a tooltip in the form. So due to some JavaScript glitch your browser submitted the form regularly instead of making an AJAX request.

Comment: The message itself is OK. I will try it again later - may really an browser/AJAX problem. Thanks.